# Test creation of specific directory and its contents via bats

Tags: testing, bats-core

I am invoking an interactive cli tool I have created (using `go` but that's not in the question's scope).

I am performing integration tests on it using a combination of [BATS](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) and `expect`.

Here is the specific test suite:

```
@test "Running interactive test - providing clone directory parameter" {
    cd test_expect
    eval "./basic_interactive.exp"
}
```

The success of this step is the creation of a specific directory with pre-defined contents.

Since I am new to `BATS` I cannot find a way to somehow assert that the command

```
ls -1 /path/to/directory/that/is/supposed/to/be/created
```

will equal

```
file1
file2
file3
```

etc.

Any suggestions?

I have tried this

```
@test "Running interactive test - providing clone directory parameter" {
    cd test_expect
    eval "./basic_interactive.exp"
    eval "ls -1 path/to/directory/that/is/supposed/to/be/created"
    echo $output
}
```

but it does not print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you basically want to run a command and validate the output, correct?

Quoting from [the BATS manual](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#run-test-other-commands)

> Bats includes a `run` helper that invokes its arguments as a command, saves the exit status and output into special global variables

The two variables that are available inside a BATS test method to validate output are:

- `$output`, which contains the combined contents of the command's **standard output** and **standard error** streams
- the `$lines` array, for easily accessing individual lines of output

Applying this to your example would give us:

```sh
@test "Running interactive test - providing clone directory parameter" {
    cd test_expect
    ./basic_interactive.exp

    run ls -1 path/to/directory/that/is/supposed/to/be/created

    expected=$(cat <<-TXT
file1
file2
file3
TXT
)

    [ "${output}" = "${expected}" ]
}
```

If you find yourself using BATS more often (or for more complex tests) you might consider using a dedicated asserts library (like [bats-assert](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-assert)) to make your life a bit easier.

(Especially the `assert_output` command is worth looking into, as it supports literal, partial, and regex matching).

To understand why you are not seeing any output, you will need to read [the section in the manual titled *"Printing to the terminal"*](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core#printing-to-the-terminal). In short it boils down to output only being shown when redirected to file descriptor 3:

```sh
@test "test with output to terminal" {
    echo "# This will show up when you run the test" >&3
}
```